# Utilizing Dynamic Parallelism in PyTorch C++ (LibTorch)

Tags: python, c++, parallel-processing, pytorch, libtorch

I am working on a project where we load a TorchScript model into C++. We have tried to make a model utilizing dynamic parallelism as described in [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/torch-script-parallelism.html) tutorial. When we do inference with the model in Python, we can see that the forward pass is parallelized by using the PyTorch profiler (also described in the link above). However, when we load the model into C++ and do inference there, the profiler tool shows that no parallelism occurs. Some more details: we use `torch.jit.fork` and `torch.jit.wait` to parallelize the forward pass in the model. Before the model is trained (in Python), we convert it to a script with `torch.jit.script`. We then train the model and save it with `model.save()`. The model is then loaded into C++ as a byte stream: `model_ptr = std::make_unique<torch::jit::Module>(torch::jit::load(input_stream))`. Finally, we do the inference in C++: `output_t = (model_ptr->forward(inp_vec)).toTensor()`. This produces the right output, but, as mentioned, no parallelization occurs. Is even dynamic parallelism of `jit::Modules` supported in C++?